# Minimum value using a Normal distribution?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I am really struggling on how to work out the minimum value when it comes to using a Normal distribution. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Example:

Say a shop is selling an item, and I have a mean of £33.50 and standard deviation of £4.
How would I work out the minimum price of the item if the shop wants to price the item in the top 7% or above of the market?

Comment: Please do not delete and repost your questions. This is probably the third time you are asking this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are  you familiar with standardization and Gaussian tables?

Set

$$\mathbb{P}[X>x]=0.07$$

$$\mathbb{P}[X\leq x]=0.93$$

... Standardize...

$$\Phi\Bigg[\frac{x-33.5}{4}\Bigg]=0.93$$

... use gaussian table to find

$$\frac{x-33.5}{4}=1.48 \rightarrow x=39.42$$

Or a calculator to find a more precise result

$$\frac{x-33.5}{4}=1.4758 \rightarrow x=39.40$$

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the Z tables?

Comment: @shrewd.jude :  yes, of course...Z tables

Comment: thanks for this. Just a question - where did you get 1.48 from?

Comment: @shrewd.jude : I enclosed a z-table image in my answer...

Comment: Ah, that is very clear. So you went to 0.08 instead of 0.07 on the table because it gives the value 0.9306, which is the value you from step one, as I want 7% and 93% is left over?

Comment: @shrewd.jude : Exactly I chose the nearest value from 93% in the table. The exact value is between 1.47 and 1.48, exactly  1,4757910282 ...

Comment: Right - got you! Thank you so much for taking the time to do this. I can now solve the other questions I have that are similar to this.